# Cannot invoke "com.android.ddmlib.EmulatorConsole.kill()" because "console" is null

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I'm facing a problem with the emulator. The System UI stops working, so I close it, but then the emulator just vanishes.

When I try to stop the emulator, I get an error that says, "Cannot invoke 'com.android.ddmlib.EmulatorConsole.kill()' because 'console' is null." Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

What you need do is to stop the virtual device from running and try again. Give it time to boot up.